# GPUImage - Tried to overrelease a framebuffer when blending too often

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

Using `GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter`, I also have a slider in the `UI` that allows me to change the **mix**. It works great, I can really move the slider around fast back and forth, but it will often give me this error if I'm sliding too fast or sliding around for over a few seconds:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to overrelease a framebuffer, did you forget to call -useNextFrameForImageCapture before using -imageFromCurrentFramebuffer?

It's coming from the unlock function in **GPUImage/framework/Source/GPUImageFramebuffer.m:269**

According to Brad Larson's [Framebuffer Article](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2014/03/17/switching-gpuimage-use-cached-framebuffers), useNextFrameForImageCapture isn't needed explicitly because imageByFilteringImage will take care of this already. But somehow the framebuffercount is getting out of sync, perhaps because it just couldn't keep up with the fast requests for updates.

I'm wondering if there's something that I'm not doing correctly. Any ideas?

Code below is basically doing:
1. First calling a setup filter to get everything setup
2. As the slider is moving, `applyAndGetCIImage` is called with the slider.

```
public class StylePhotoFilter: PhotoFilter {
  var blendFilter: GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter!
  var originalImage: UIImage!
  var styledImage: UIImage!
  var styledImageSource: GPUImagePicture!

  override func setupFilter() {

    // setup the filters
    blendFilter = GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter()

    // setting up the image to edit
    if(uiImage == nil) {
      let context = CIContextManager.sharedInstance
      let cgiImgRef = context.createCGImage(inputImage, fromRect: inputImage.extent())
      originalImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgiImgRef)
    } else {
      originalImage = uiImage!
    }

    // apply the style fully
    // styledImage = // I created this image earlier, we can assume it works

    // add target photo
    styledImageSource = GPUImagePicture(image: styledImage)
    styledImageSource.addTarget(blendFilter, atTextureLocation: 0)

  }

  public override func applyAndGetCIImage(sliderVal: Float) -> CIImage! {
    // set the mix
    blendFilter.mix = sliderVal

    // blend it
    // blendFilter.useNextFrameForImageCapture() // According to Brad Larson, this is no longer needed, as imageByFilteringImage does this for you
    styledImageSource.processImage()
    let blendedImage = blendFilter.imageByFilteringImage(originalImage)

    return CIImage(image: blendedImage)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Method `useNextFrameForImageCapture` should be applied to filter, but not to picture.

```
blendFilter = GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter()
blendFilter.useNextFrameForImageCapture()
```

Comment: Interesting. So I tried that too, but still the same error. This works for awhile, but only errors when I move the slider around a lot.

Comment: Moving the slider works fine. As soon as I move it really quickly for a few seconds, it crashes. Almost like it's not thread safe.

Comment: This seems to improve it a bit but I'm still getting the asertion. I'm using GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter to render dynamic text onto the video. Calling [filter useNextFrameForImageCapture] before updating my source picture caused the assertion to pass more often than not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you but I was seeing that issue as well and added this code to the main loop and it fixed it.  There seems to be an issue with the reference counting.

```
GPUImageFramebuffer* fb = self.filter.framebufferForOutput;
[fb disableReferenceCounting];
```